# SAS Summing a dynamic range in array

Tags: arrays, sas

I have an array with totals for 210 days. I need to find the sum of all 90 day ranges. The new array is med_sum. So med_sum(1) =sum(of Total(32)-total(121)), then med_sum(2)=sum(of total(33)-total(122)), and so on, 90 different times all the way to med_sum(90)=sum(of total(121)-total(210)).
Below is the syntax, but the sum(of) function isn't allowing me to do this and errors out. I have tried quite a few different options but have been unable to find anything that works.
Thank you in advance!!

```
data work.total_base_3;
set work.total_base_2;
array med_total(*) total1-total210;
array med_sum(*) avg1-avg90;
do i = 1 to 90;
med_sum(i)=sum(of med_total(i+31)-med_total(i+120));
end;
run;
```

Comment: Do you get an error in the log? Or just an unexpected result?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @Trinity.  Some sample input and desired output data may assist in getting answers.

Comment: I am getting the below error message.

Comment: 22         
23         GOPTIONS ACCESSIBLE;
24         data work.total_base_3;
25         set work.total_base_2;
26         array med_total(*) total1-total210;
27         array med_sum(*) avg1-avg90;
28         do i = 1 to 90;
29         med_sum(i)=sum(of med_total(i+31)-med_total(i+120));
                                            _
                                            22
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: ), ','.  

30         end;
31         run;

Comment: Not really sure how to do sample data, as it would be too large. Basically I just want to sum total(32) through total(121). Then shift over one. sum total(33) through total(122). 90 different times. Total(*) represents a day. I want to sum each 90 day subset.

Comment: You cannot refer to arrays in SAS like this :( What you can do is modify your loop and do two nested loops to calculate the sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use array references in variable lists, just actual variable names. So you want to generate 90 sums of 90 values with the window sliding. In essence you want

```
avg1 = sum(of total32 - total121);
avg2 = sum(of total33 - total122);
avg3 = sum(of total34 - total123);
```

You could use macro logic to just generate that series of statements.  But if you look at the relationship between the variables you can see that

```
med_sum(n+1) = sum(med_sum(n),med_total(n+1+120),-1*med_total(n+31));
```

So your loop will look something like:

```
med_sum(1) = sum(of total32-total121);
do n=1 to dim(med_sum)-1;
  med_sum(n+1) = sum(med_sum(n),med_total(n+1+120),-1*med_total(n+31));
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a sample that you should be able to extend to your data (so in your case you would change the 3's to 90's):

case 1 Data in rows :

```
data test;
keep obs;
do i=1 to 10;
   obs = i;
   output;
end;
run;

data test1;
set test;
keep obs sum;
array x[3];
retain x;
x[mod(_n_ -1,3)+1] = obs;
if (_n_ >= 3)then do;
   sum = 0;
   do i = 1 to 3;
      sum= sum + x[i];
   end;
end;
run;
```

case 2 data in columns (use the test dataset from from above):

```
proc transpose data=test out=testrow;
var  obs;
run;

data test2;
set testrow;
array med_total(*) col1-col10;
array med_sum(8) ;
do i = 3 to 10;
  med_sum[i-2]=0;
  do j = 1 +(i-3) to i;
     med_sum(i-2)=med_sum[i-2] + med_total(j);
  end;
end;
run;
```

Comment: Sorry. I am still newer to SAS, and am not getting the results I'd expect. Not sure this will work for what I am trying to do